# Random function for any possible positive number but likely close to zero

Tags: performance, algorithm, random

I'm looking for a random number function which will potentially return any (positive) number, but is statistically unlikely to be far from zero. I have an algorithm which will work for my needs, but seems inefficient:

```
def my_random():
    if random.randrange(2):
        return 1 + my_random()
    return 0
```

I know could rewrite it without recursion, but that doesn't really negate the inefficiency. Can anyone suggest and alternative algorithm which has better performance?

My implementation language is python, but the algorithm is what's important.

Comment: The answers to this question may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14266717/random-number-python-with-gaussian-distribution

Comment: You might want to search "random number logarithmic distribution" there are some great solutions (some on stack overflow)

Comment: Are you willing to accept an upper bound on the produced number?

Comment: P.S. Have you tried timing this function? The performance only suffers when you get a large output, which is statistically unlikely. 99% of the returned values will be 6 or less.

Comment: Yes, I understand that it's unlikely that the function takes very long, but in a server situation, I'd prefer to avoid the possibility of a hang

Comment: A very large upper bound would be acceptable, if the distribution was correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a function that returns a random float in the range `[0, 1)`, such as Python's `random.random`, then you can sample from an [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) by

```
def random_exponential(scale=1.):
    x = random.random()
    return -math.log(1. - x) * scale
```

(Inspired by the NumPy source code, which I was just reading; you can also call `np.random.exponential` if using NumPy is an option.)

If you need random integers, consider truncating these.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I want. At least I know the name for it now. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Python already has random exponential and random normal functions, but they are not implemented any better than your simple code above.  If you need better performance, find a library that uses the Ziggurat algorithm (like my http://github.com/lcrocker/ojrandlib)